# Chi-boundedness and Upperbounds on Chromatic Number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am new to graph theory and am a bit confused about the difference b/w the chi-boundedness and upper-bounds on chromatic number. Can we say that chi-boundedness is a form of an upperbound of the chromatic number? Could someone help me to clarify?

### Definitions

- Chromatic Number: Minimal number of colours needed to colour the vertices in such a way that no two adjacent vertices have the same colour
- Chi-boundedness: Ideal(I) is chi-bounded if there is a func f, called chi-bounding func, s.t. $\chi$(G) < f($\omega$(G)) for all G in I

  - I understand that chi-boundedness basically considers the following question: If a graph has bounded clique number and sufficiently large chromatic number, what can we say about its induced subgraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of $\chi$-boundedness is a generalization of perfect graphs. A graph $G$ is perfect if $\chi(H)=\omega(H)$ for each induced subgraph $H$ of $G$.

A graph $G$ is $\chi$-bounded if there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\chi(H) \leq f(\omega(H))$ for each induced subgraph $H$ of $G$.

If we let $f:\omega \mapsto \omega$ (the identity function), then $G$ is a perfect graph iff $G$ is $\chi$-bounded by $f$. Hence, the above is a direct generalization.

In that sense, a $\chi$-binding function is an upper bound for the chromatic number, but in form of a function from its clique number $\omega$ to a natural number.

For example, the class of even-hole-free graphs, that is the class of graphs that forbidds induced cycles of even length, is $\chi$-bounded with $\chi$-binding function $\chi(G) \leq 2\omega(G)-1$ as shown by Addario-Berry et.al.

**Question:** Are all graphs $\chi$-bounded by some function $f$? No. There are graphs that are triangle free, thus clique number strictly smaller than $3$, but with an arbitrary large chromatic number (consider the Mycielskian construction for an example).

Answering the question whether or not a given family of graphs is $\chi$-bounded or not is far from trivial and an open research question for many classes of graphs.

There is another interesting problem.

**Problem:** Given a class of graphs that is $\chi$-bounded by some function $f$. Is $f$ the smallest $\chi$-binding function for this class?

Answering the above is an open research question for many graph classes.

Your second questions asks what we can say about the induced subgraphs of a graph $G$ if we are provided with a $\chi$-binding function. For a concrete graph, these are the usual answers one could provide if we know the chromatic number of a graph  (which is the same as saying we know the $\chi$-binding function of a specific graph that provides a tight bound). This is not interesting. It is more interesting to consider a whole family of graphs and its $\chi$-binding function, because it allows us to make certain statements about the structure of the whole family.

Is there a general answer about the structure of a class of graphs if we know its $\chi$-binding function? I am afraid that there is none, but I can't say this for sure.

If you want to dive deeper into this topic, I suggest the following two survey papers:

[1] "Schiermeyer, Ingo, and Bert Randerath. "Polynomial $\chi$-Binding Functions and Forbidden Induced Subgraphs: A Survey." Graphs and Combinatorics 35.1 (2019): 1-31."

[2] "Scott, A., & Seymour, P. (2020). A survey of χ-boundedness." (I have only found it on arXiv)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I was reading [2] but was not aware of [1]! I will definitely check it out soon! Btw, in the definition of $\chi$-boundedness for a graph, why do we need the condition that the binding fn applies to all the induced subgraph? I think in [2](as far as I've read), they didn't mention that... Or I think I might've just misread the context of the definition?

Comment: oh, do you think "Ideal" part of my definition above actually meant "Class of graphs that essentially are just subgraphs belonging to some given graph"?

Comment: Sorry, pls ignore my above question coming from the confusion of the part of the definition! I went over few more definitions on the internet and now it makes sense!!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: We call a class of graphs that is closed under the operation of taking induced subgraphs an „ideal“. Thus this is the same thing. First of all, we require the $\chi$-boundedness for all induced subgraphs because we want to generalize perfect graphs. But, of course this has several advantages. We get some kind of recursive property! This has advantages when it comes to the design of algorithms for example. Keep this in mind: say we‘ve proven a quadratic chi bound. This doesn’t mean we can colour the graph using $\omega^2$ colours in quadratic time.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your follow-up! I've also understood about that chi-boundedness is not about the computational complexity!

Comment: You are very welcome!